# How to set up global flag in appengine standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to set a global application setting in my app. I don't really want to use the database as it's just a single flag. I can't use Memcache because it's not durable. Not sure if env variable is shared will al instances after the change?
This setting might be changed in the app (like once a month)

Is there any other Google Service where I could place it? There will be quite a lot of reads

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

- Store it in your code.
- Store it in an environment variable.  This will be the same for all instances.
- Store it in datastore but read the value into a Python module variable so you don't need to access the datastore to use it after the first time.
- Google recently deployed "[Secrets management](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs)".  I haven't tried it yet, but it could work for this.